# Import eclipse Kepler syntax highlighting and color theme into eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna, scala-ide

There are numerous recipes for transferring those settings between eclipse installations, admittedly all of them quite hackish. Yet, replicating your settings when upgrading from Kepler to Luna can take a whole afternoon. I imagine you can also mess things up quite nicely if you overwrite Luna-specific configuration with Kepler ones or vice versa, unless eclipse committers use some special conventions or facilities to avoid that happening...

What would be a good way of transferring your entire editor-related color themes, font settings, and syntax highlighting settings from Kepler to Luna?

Comment: Generally the configuration keys don't change between releases. If you use the same workspace everything should just work.

Comment: I have a side-by-side configuration. I use Kepler for Scala-IDE for Scala 2.10, and Luna for Scala-IDE for Scala 2.11.. I don't think sharing workspaces between two active versions is supposed to work, so I must need to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

I copied mostly everything of what was mentioned in the linked question, plus in my case `org.scala-ide.*`, between the old and new eclipse `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` directories.

It looks fine but to say this was ugly would be a really odd understatement. It is my hope that future changes I will make in Luna settings will not break resulting from this process. This question still awaits a much better answer in my humble view.